# How to register multiple Spring configuration file?

Tags: java, spring

I have two Spring configuration file.the one is named MongoConfiguration：

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan("com.vmojing.mongodb")

public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "demo";
    }
    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {

        return new Mongo(new ArrayList<ServerAddress>() {{ add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017));}});

    }
    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.vmojing.mongodb.domain";
    }
 }
```

The other is named SpringConfiguration using to define some bean:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.vmojing.mongodb")
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BasicRepository<Topic> topicDao(){
        return new BasicRepository<Topic>(Topic.class);
    }   
}
```

I using this code to register them:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext a = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        a.register(MongoConfiguration.class);
        a.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
        a.refresh();
        ApplicationContext context = a;
```

But,it doesn't work.When I just register "MongoConfiguration.class",it work normally.How to  register multiple Spring configuration file ?

Comment: Have one "root" configuration file and locate "child" configuration files somewhere in the `@ComponentScan` area. Spring will pick them up during the scan.

Comment: How to locate "child" configuration files?Can give me some usage?Tanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. Surely you know what `@ComponentScan` does? Why do you have the same value in both files?

Comment: Thanks,I'm beginner learning Spring.Now,I know the project only need a @ComponentScan.I want to locate "MongoConfiguration ".

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm sorry for my description,I have found the solution using "@Import({ SpringConfiguration.class })".Thank you for your answer,it really help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to register them manually. Thats `@Configuration`  responsibility to point spring that this particular file should be counted as config.

Also dont use same `@ComponentScan` in two files. How do you bootstrap spring into your application? You should have class extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter somewhere there.

Comment: I don't know how to  locate other configuration,and my project isn't web project